# Proving the upper bound of the sequence in converging power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, limsup-and-liminf, upper-lower-bounds

> For a converging(the radius of convergence $0 < r < \infty$)
>   complex power series $\displaystyle \sum a_n z^n$ prove that there
>   exists a positive number $C$ such that if $\displaystyle A > \frac{1}{r}$
>   then $$\lvert a_n \rvert \le CA^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

So I tried this: We know that
$$\frac{1}{r} = \limsup_n\lvert a_n \rvert^{1/n}$$
Let's construct a series $\displaystyle \sum_n \left(\frac{1}{A}\right)^n\lvert a_n \rvert$ then by the root test, it converges because
$$\limsup_n \left(\frac{1}{A}\right) \lvert a_n \rvert^{1/n} < 1$$
So the sequence converges, then it is bounded. Then there exists a positive number $C$ such that
$$\lvert a_n \rvert \le CA^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
I think my proof is too nasty and it proves existence depending on $A$. How should I prove this?